# How can I select between record without where in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, between

I want to select records between 50 and 100 without `where` in `select` statement.

How can I do that ?

Comment: does that column is unique and continuous as1,2,3,4......?

Comment: @koushikveldanda , yeah that is IDENTITY column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY column
 OFFSET 50 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

it will work only if you have every number between 50-100...

some times gaps will created when insertion is failed so at that tym it will gives the rows which was not included in the 50-100...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM
   (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Your_Table) AS Tb
ORDER BY Your_Column DESC
```

Comment: this statement export is between 50 and 100 ?

Comment: query should be flexible. it's look like hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select * from table a inner join table b 
    on a.ID=b.ID and a.ID between 50 and 100
```

Comment: it states without using where